# Facebook share link UNWANTED image

Tags: asp.net, facebook, button, web, share

I have a strange problem and my PM requires me to fix it. None of my colleagues could help me.

I've added a functionality to existing ASP.NET WebForms page. I involves a button to share the link by facebook. But when sharing in someone's profile a strange image of Adobe is appearing:

[Undesired Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2MR3.jpg)

It is even more strange that after a few seconds it disappeares. Tried everything - to give a parameter to the facebook URL with **images[0]**, also from the meta tags in the master page. No result. Supposed the facebook may have cached the link, but when I tried from my home PC the result was the same.

Any advice how to remove the adobe pic?

Comment: Check your OG meta implementation using the debug tool. This will also clear Facebook’s cache for the object. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Already did. It's showing the default picture, although all meta tags are clearly in the page.

Comment: Well then give us an example URL where we can have a look ourselves.

Comment: http://marketsrally.osystems-tech.com/?ref=126  This link I give as a parameter to the fb url

Comment: And the debug tool shows explicit errors/warnings for this … so go fix them.

Comment: Yes, this is the issue. My fixing is not working. If you see all  meta tags are in the header of the page

Comment: Yes, but some with empty or wrong values (at least that’s what I see in the source code of your page, and the FB scraper seems to see the same): `<meta property="og:url" />`, `<meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID" />` (literally), `<meta property="og:description" />`

Comment: OK. URL I leave empty, because I fill it later with javascipt. There is an important parameter that must be passed with this URL. About description, I decided to leave empty and for user id have no Idea what to put. Does this properties values matter for validation?

Comment: You can not set them “later” with JavaScript, because the FB scraper does not “speak” JS. Everything must be in the HTML source of the URL. And you are getting an _error_ now about the `USER_ID` value – so fix that first, and see what messages you get then.

Comment: OK thanks man. I removed user ID and set the facebook URL, now is working. I'll test if my parameter will still be passed. Is this URL overriding what link I will insert later to be shared be facebook?